# Prooftree within a table?

Tags: tables, tabularx, includegraphics, logic, bussproofs

**1.Question**
I am trying to construct a table with two columns and one row such that:

- The first column consists of a letter (centered vertically) and on its right hand side there is an image
- The second column consists of a proof written via the bussproofs package
- Each cell is centered vertically and horizontally
- The table does not exceed the textwidth

How can I achieve what I want?

**2.Attempt**
My attempt looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\textwidth}{17cm}
\hoffset -20mm \topmargin= -13mm

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X|X}
$\alpha_{A,B,C}^{\otimes} =$

\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}& 

\AxiomC{\strut}
\RightLabel{(Ax)}
\UnaryInfC{$A \vdash A$}
\AxiomC{\strut}
\RightLabel{(Ax)}
\UnaryInfC{$B \vdash B$}
\AxiomC{\strut}
\RightLabel{(Ax)}
\UnaryInfC{$C \vdash C$}
\RightLabel{$(\otimes R)$}
\BinaryInfC{$B,C \vdash B \otimes C$}
\RightLabel{$(\otimes R)$}
\BinaryInfC{$A,B,C \vdash A \otimes (B \otimes C)$}
\RightLabel{$(\otimes L)$}
\UnaryInfC{$A\otimes B,C \vdash A \otimes (B \otimes C)$}
\RightLabel{$(\otimes L)$}
\UnaryInfC{$(A\otimes B) \otimes C \vdash A \otimes (B \otimes C)$}
\DisplayProof
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

This is compiled something like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Please supply a working example.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum Is it better now?

Comment: Yes. It now compiles without errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to vertically center an image relative to the baseline, I'd suggest using the `adjustbox` package with the `export` option. This loads graphicx, so it doesn't need to be loaded separately, but adds an option `valign` for aligning the image relative to the baseline of the text. You can use `m` for "middle".

If I understand you right, you want the `$\alpha_{A,B,C}^{\otimes} =$` in the first cell to the left of the image and not above it? If so, you can't put a blank line between it and the `\includegraphics` command, since that is being interpreted as a paragraph break. Make sure the image is scaled so that both it and the start fit on the same line.

`bussproofs` are already centered vertically relative to the baseline; to get horizontal centering in an `X` column, you can define a new column type with `\centering\arraybackslash` added to the cells.

Finally I added `\noindent` before the tabularx, since it was being indented as the start of new paragraph which made it not fit quite right. That, together with using tabularx with the width set to `\textwidth`, as you already had it, should make the table the right width, provided the content fits.

Here is my suggestion:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\setlength{\textwidth}{17cm}
\hoffset -20mm \topmargin= -13mm

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{x}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{x|x}
$\alpha_{A,B,C}^{\otimes} =$
\includegraphics[valign=m,scale=0.5]{example-image-a}&
\AxiomC{\strut}
\RightLabel{(Ax)}
\UnaryInfC{$A \vdash A$}
\AxiomC{\strut}
\RightLabel{(Ax)}
\UnaryInfC{$B \vdash B$}
\AxiomC{\strut}
\RightLabel{(Ax)}
\UnaryInfC{$C \vdash C$}
\RightLabel{$(\otimes R)$}
\BinaryInfC{$B,C \vdash B \otimes C$}
\RightLabel{$(\otimes R)$}
\BinaryInfC{$A,B,C \vdash A \otimes (B \otimes C)$}
\RightLabel{$(\otimes L)$}
\UnaryInfC{$A\otimes B,C \vdash A \otimes (B \otimes C)$}
\RightLabel{$(\otimes L)$}
\UnaryInfC{$(A\otimes B) \otimes C \vdash A \otimes (B \otimes C)$}
\DisplayProof
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: buss proof example]

Comment: That was helpful, many thanks!